# Given $\int _{-1}^{1}g(x)= 1$ show that $\int _{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)\geq 1$ for certain $f,g$.

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive valued functions defined on $[-1,1]$, such that $f(x)f(-x)=1$, and $g$ is an even function with $\int _{-1}^{1}g(x)= 1$.

Show that $\int _{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)\geq 1$.

I don't know how to proceed with the problem. Any solution/hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the integral in $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$. Since $g$ is even, we have $\int_0^1 g(t)dt=1/2$. Now,

$$\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt=\int_{-1}^0f(t)g(t)dt+\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt=\int_0^1f(-t)g(-t)dt+\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt=\int_0^1(f(t)+f(-t))g(t)dt=\int_0^1(f(t)+\frac{1}{f(t)})g(t)dt,$$
where the next-to-last equality uses that $g$ is even and the last equality uses $f(t)f(-t)=1$. Now you need to verify that for $x\geq 0$, the equation $x+\frac{1}{x}$ attains its minimum at $x=1$, so $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$. Using the fact that $f(t)>0$, we have
$$\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)\geq\int_0^12g(t)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Split the integral, do a substitution on the second one, use $f(x)f(-x)=1$, and recombine to get
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x)dx = \int_0^1 \left( f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)} \right) g(x) dx.$$
Next show that $y+1/y \geq 2$ for $y > 0$. Can you finish?

Comment: Sure, you are right