# Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive valued functions defined on $[-1,1]$, such that $f(x)f(-x)=1$, and $g$ is an even function with

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, problem-solving

Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive valued functions defined on $[-1,1]$, such that $f(x)f(-x)=1$, and $g$ is an even function with $\int _{-1}^{1}g(x)= 1$. Then $I=\int _{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx$  satisfies

$$A.I\geq 1\quad \quad B.I\leq 1\quad \quad  C. \frac13<I<3 \quad \quad  D.I=1$$

My partial solution goes like this:

> If we put $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=|x|$ , then, both $f,g$ satisfies all the given conditions. Also, we find  $$I=\int _{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx=\int _{-1}^{0} f(x)g(x) dx+\int _{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx=\int _{-1}^{0} -e^xx dx+\int _{0}^{1} xe^xdx\geq 1.$$  This procedure eliminates, options  $B$ and $D.$

Now, how to determine the correct option between $A.$ and $C.$ ? Also, in this casez I think, I was just "lucky enough" to find such an example for the functions $f,g$. But how to solve these problems in an mcq (Multiple Choice Question) test where one have a time constraint ? I dont get it.

Comment: I am not sure what the answer would be if $f$ is required to be continuous, but since it is not, let $f = N$ on $[-1,0)$; $f=1$ at $x=0$; $f=\frac{1}{N}$ on $(0,1]$. For $N$ sufficiently large, this rules out C. Given that this is a MCQ question, I think ruling out possible answers as you have done is the best approach.

Comment: Hint: $f(x) + f(-x) \geq 2\sqrt{f(x)f(-x) } = 2$. Hence, show that $I+I \geq 2$. If you're stuck, show your work. What condition have we not used as yet?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1763173/42969

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks for your answer! But can you elaborate, how do you conclude, "For $N$ sufficiently large, this rules out $C$ " ? I assume, that $N$ is real constant but I think, a little elaboration on this precis would be really helpful...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given $\int _{-1}^{1}g(x)= 1$ show that $\int _{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)\geq 1$ for certain $f,g$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763173/given-int-11gx-1-show-that-int-11fxgx-geq-1-for-certa)

Comment: In your example, try using $f(x)=e^{3x}$ to see what happens.  This rules out C.

Comment: @Franklin Yes, $N$ is a positive real constant. By direct evaluation, and using the evenness of $g$, it then should be clear that the integral can be made arbitrarily large (in particular, larger than $3$). This example may also help clear the doubts in your comment under M. Lavrov's answer. As for your question about "luck" -- not really. I think the ability to come up with counter-examples is fairly important in mathematics, and being able to find them (quickly) is no more about luck than for any other type of solution. However, it does therefore take practice.

Comment: @legionwhale Now, your counter example using the $N$ is sooo simpler than mine! Using your example, it is a two-step solution and takes some seconds to get the answer, not even minutes!  *There is no need of using $e^x$ and all those unnecessary things that make this problem so complicated. What do you think ?* How did you come up with this? Maybe, practice will help me build these sort of intuitions, as you suggested. Mind posting this as an answer, I will be glad to accept it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Franklin No worries. I have tried to give some more advice in an answer. Bear in mind that it did take me a few minutes, not seconds, to think of my solution :-) For more and better-written advice, you could try Polya's book, *How to Solve It*, a general-purpose guide to problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I expand my comment into an answer. There is no requirement on the continuity of $f$, so we may consider:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{N} & x < 0  \\
  1  & x = 0 \\
  N & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

for some $N \in \mathbb{R}^+$. (Note: the value of $f$ at $x=0$ is determined by the conditions given.)

Then:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx = \frac{1}{N} \int_{-1}^0 g(x) dx + N \int_0^1g(x)dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{1}{N} + N \bigg)$$

For $N$ arbitrarily large (not even that large!), we observe that only $(A):I \ge1$ will hold.

I could not be considered an authority on this topic, but here is some advice. Generally, you want to extremise when finding counterexamples -- to make a certain quantity small or large (here, the value of $I$), or to find objects which possess or lack certain crucial qualities (e.g. continuity, boundedness).

To establish which feature(s) should be extremised, you have to collect some data, of course -- try a few different approaches, plug in some numbers, and see what comes out. In particular, if you stumble across something that almost works by chance, try to identify, if any exist, the salient feature(s) that it extremises. Once these are found, try the simplest extremiser possible. In this case, it was a locally constant function, which is trivial to integrate.

Don't be afraid to over-simplify either. Suppose the question had required that $f$ was continuous. Then, note that argument carries across with an effectively identical function which is made continuous by some appropriate interpolation on an interval $( - \varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. I hope you agree that it is not even necessary here to find a formula to see that this would work. In either case, the principle of extremisation is what is key.

Lastly, think about heuristic arguments. In analysis, if a quantity can be observed to be small, there is a decent chance it can be made arbitrarily small. (Intuition will help here; similarly if we replace "small" with "large", of course.) Thus, it can be helpful to introduce new variables e.g. $N$ as above. In practical terms, we are enabled to try a family of infinite functions all at once. With the previous work, we know not only that $I$ can be larger than $3$, but that it is unbounded.

Indeed, note that, in principle, we are not even concerned with the value of $N$ which makes $I$ exceed $3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting $g(x)=|x|$ it is simpler to set $g(x)=\frac12$ if we are looking for counterexamples.

Taking $f(x) = e^x$ is one option, and gives $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^x}{2}\,dx = \frac{e - e^{-1}}{2} \approx 1.15.$$ But equally well, we can take $f(x) = e^{kx}$ for any $k$, and get $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{kx}}{2}\,dx = \frac{e^{k} - e^{-k}}{2k}.$$ For large $k$, this can be made as large as we like, ruling out (B), (C), and (D).

Even without that example in mind, we can think about what the condition on $f(x)$ actually tells us. It does not prohibit $f$ from doing literally anything we like on $(0,1]$, as long as we define its behavior on $[-1,0)$ to satisfy $f(-x) = \frac1{f(x)}$. All we need is that $f(0)=1$. So we can make $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ as large as we like, which leads to the integral in the question being large as well.

Comment: That was indeed a beautiful explanation for ruling out $C$. But thinking about these examples I think, is a point of being "lucky" in an exam. What I mean, is that, if one can think these counter examples immediately, he/she is done. But if someone haves a hard time think about it, it becomes a difficult scenario!   What do you suggest to do under such circumstances for these type of question ?

Comment: I added the reasoning in my last paragraph to address that. Think about what amount of freedom we do or do not have in the problem - and work within that freedom. (And pick examples that are as simple as possible to start with - that is why $g(x)=\frac12$ is my first choice.)

Comment: Ok, but this line,"  we can make $\int_0^1f(x)$ as large as possible" *might* be true because of the degree of freedom we enjoy here? But we need to check out $\int_{-1}^0f(x)$ to not be infinitely small as well!  But I think, we might manipulate that as we can really, *build an unimaginable amount of various sorts of  of functions* but **I just don't get a justification of how to intuitively or reason out  why $\int_-1^1f(x)$** can be as large as we want ?...

Comment: Even if $\int_{-1}^0 f(x)$ is "infinitely small", it is still positive, so we don't have to worry about that side of the integral hurting us. I feel like it's not hard to intuitively reason that if we have complete freedom to draw a function on $[0,1]$ (subject to $f(0)=1$) we can make sure the area below it is bigger than $3$.

Comment: Ok, now that sounds convincing! Correct me if I am wrong :  We are in back of our mind, have a pre-conceived idea about the transcendental (and unimaginable ) number and forms of functions that can be created! So, really, we can say, we can do anything with $f(x)$ to make $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ as large as possible and we need no justification for this assertion. This seems pretty obvious, as no restriction is defined on $f$ except that $\frac1f$ should be defined. *Is this what you meant* ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1 from me, really, a good answer! I remain grateful...